# How to remove all unnecessary tables from the data dictionary view CAT?

Tags: oracle, dictionary, plsql

I want to remove all unnecessary objects from the data dictionary view CAT (all objects without a $). How do I do that?

Comment: you mean delete ? `delete from table where objects like '%$%'`

Answer (score 1):

You don't. It's a system view and it's highly inadvisable to do anything of the sort. If you want all objects with a $ then simply select that:

```
select * from cat where table_name like '%$%'
```

I'm personally not a fan of Oracle's synonyms for the system views. They have a habit of deprecating them for a start. I'd use [USER_CATALOG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_1031.htm#REFRN20036) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Don't do that, you would destroy your database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an unnecessary table, you drop it, e.g.:

```
DROP TABLE x;
```

It will then be removed from the data dictionary views.